# swagger not working with grape

Tags: ruby-on-rails, swagger, ruby-grape

I'm configuring swagger in my rails grape application. I have grape working right. The swagger-grape files are been created

But when i go to swagger url it shows

```
fetching resource list: http://localhost:3000/api/api_docs.json
```

This is my api.rb file

```
class API < Grape::API
  format :json
  formatter :json, Grape::Formatter::ActiveModelSerializers

  before do
    header["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
    header["Access-Control-Request-Method"] = "*"
    unless Rails.env.test?
      log = Rails.logger
      log.info [request.env["REQUEST_METHOD"], request.env["REQUEST_PATH"]]
      log.info request.body.read
    end
  end

  mount Kodomo::Status

  base_path_proc = Proc.new do |r|
    if Rails.env.development?
      "http://#{r.host}:#{r.port}"
    else
      "http://#{r.host}"
    end
  end
  add_swagger_documentation mount_path: "api_docs",
                            api_version: "v4",
                            hide_documentation_path: true,
                            hide_format: true,
                            base_path: base_path_proc
end
```

The /api/api-docs is generated correctly so i have no idea of that could it be.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time doing tests i discovered that the problem was the version o swagger-ui that i had downloaded from the repo. When i set the swagger to a older version it worked great.